# Particle hair colour

Tags: particles, hair

Let's say I have a carpet with a picture of an ornament as a texture. The carpet is black and the  ornament white. I want the carpet to be with hair particles. My question is how can I colour the hair particles that form the ornament.

Comment: How detailed is Your ornament? if it is not to detailed, I would subdivide the mesh until I could weight paint the ornament manually via an overlay ref image.

Comment: @sorenfroststaal that's my problem, it's complex https://previews.123rf.com/images/turr17/turr171502/turr17150200235/36237627-floral-vector-oriental-pattern-with-arabesque-and-floral-elements-abstract-ornament-for-background-b.jpg (i've removed in photoshop the white trademark letters)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I tried to see if it was possible to model the pattern and got this result. I took a plane in top down mode and modelled it on top of the referance picture, and via array modifier and mirror came up with this result. I dont know if it is useable, as the computer I am currently using have some troubles, and crashes during hair simulation. Try it out and let me know if you can get some good results. You can add two seperate hair modifiers as it is 2 different meshes. So it should be possible. I am uncertain if the resolution of the mesh is high enough, or if the scene become too system heavy. Also there might be an issue with the hair modifier clutching the same amount of hair on the small faces as on the large faces.

The file is spread on 3 layers, so you can see some of the progress, and also contain the meshes before the modifiers are applied.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all you work, but I was looking for a simple/automatic method, I mean what you did is time-consuming. I can't believe that blender doesn't a have an option for this. It's so basic. What if you want to make a tiger fur with the stripes and stuff. Or something more complex than this ornament. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: Yearh! I know what you mean! I actually also thought of the tiger example! I can’t believe it either..